# Detect JFrame resize

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I use a `JFrame`, which I'd like, as soon as the user resizes it from its original size (400x300) and the `width` reaches a value, to do some things, let's call it a print command here. I use:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DC extends JFrame {
    public DC() {
        setSize(400, 300);
        setVisible(true);
        if (getWidth() >= 1000) System.out.print("Thousand");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DC dc = new DC();
        dc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

This works but only if I `setSize(1000, 300)` from the beginning for example, and not when the user resizes the frame. I am knew to swing and such and I think this is not the way to approach this. Where should I look to fix this? Ty

Comment: You should be able to us a ComponentListener

Comment: *"..let's call it a print command here"*  No.  Let's call it what it actually is.  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your new modified code **(Will print Thousand as soon as the window's width size is greater than equal to 1000)**----

```
import java.awt.Component; //import these 3 header files
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DC extends JFrame {
    public DC() {
        setSize(400, 300);
        setVisible(true);
       // if (getWidth() >= 1000) System.out.print("Thousand");
        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() 
        {  
                public void componentResized(ComponentEvent evt) {
                    Component c = (Component)evt.getSource();
                    if(c.getWidth()>=1000) //This will print Thousand
                    {
                    System.out.println("Thousand");
                    }
                }
        });
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DC dc = new DC();
        dc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```